# Connector/Net no longer supports server versions prior to 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, backup

I'm using MySqlBackup.dll for mysql database backup in my asp.net application.
At the time of backup it troughs an error

### Message

```
 Connector/Net no longer supports server versions prior to 5.0
```

What is this and how can i remove this error message.

Comment: You can't remove the message since its generate by the library.  Verify your not using MySQL prior to 5.0

Comment: And also if it was possible, removing the message will do any good to the problem. That DLL doesn't work with a database version prior to 5.0

Comment: Just try to backup it by code (the classic method)